# how many cluster can anyone made in mongodb atlas free access?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have created one free Mongodb atlas cluster. if I create another free cluster in another project, is there any chance that my previous cluster will be deleted or remove??
I am confused about their restriction on free access.

Comment: That sounds more like a question for the MongoDB Atlas support team than for the programming community.

Comment: MongoDB free tier comes with a limit of 1 M0 cluster per atlas project.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Atlas's free tier allows for up to 250 projects, each with an M0 cluster. However, only one M0 free cluster can be created per project.
Here are some other limits for MongoDB Atlas's free tier:

- 500 connections
- 500 collections
- 100 crud requests per second
- 16 MB maximum document size
- 100 database users per project

Comment: does that mean I can have multiple "maxed out" Free Tier Databases in a single Atlas account, as long as I use different projects? Or will there be restrictions for the whole account?